# quotes within a string

Tags: python, string, quotes

I am attempting to feed a string to the terminal from python but I can't get my string formatted correctly.

```
c="awk -F\"\t\" '{print$5\" \"$6\" \"$7}' file.txt | sort | uniq -c"
```

when you look at this in the shell you get:

```
>>> f="awk -F\"\t\" '{print$5\" \"$6\" \"$7}' file.txt | sort | uniq -c"
>>> f
'awk -F"\t" \'{print$5" "$6" "$7}\' file.txt | sort | uniq -c'
```

Why are there \'s before the single quotes? How do I get rid of them?
I have tried """string""" and '''string'''

In a previous program i  had this:

```
>>> t="awk '{print $4}' file.txt | sort | uniq"
>>> t
"awk '{print $4}' file.txt | sort | uniq"
```

I'm not sure what the difference is

Comment: Try typing `print(f)` rather than just `f`.

Comment: It prints fine, but Im using it in the subprocess.Popen function and I don't think the print form of the string is what is passed to the terminal

Comment: What you are viewing in the `repr` (representation) of `f`, which is displayed as a single-quoted string as you noticed, so it has to escape other single quotes. When printed it is not enclosed in quotes, because you are not seeing the `repr` of it. You could have tested similarly when using `subprocess.Popen`. Why not pass it into `echo` just to be sure?

Comment: To answer your question about why `t` came out different - I believe that it has to do with the fact that `t` contains single quotes, and `string`'s `__repr__` normally shows single-quoted strings but will use double-quoted strings if it can in order to avoid showing escaped quotes. Or something like that. Just know what you must escape whatever quote style you use to enclose the string when not triple-quoting it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is to use a raw triple-quoted string.

```
f = r"""awk -F"\t" '{print$5" "$6" "$7}' file.txt | sort | uniq -c"""
```